# Is RunOnceServices still supported in Win10?

Tags: windows, windows-10, windows-registry, .net-framework

I found few references that Windows 10 should support `RunOnceServices` registry key on path

`Computer\HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\RunServicesOnce`

this should work in similar way as Run or RunOnce.
What I'm trying to achieve is to schedule upgrade of .NET on next startup before user perform logon so my registry is REG_SZ with value

```
"C:\MyFolder\ndp48-x86-x64-allos-enu.exe /q /forcerestart"
```

It does not make change whether I wrap my command with `"` or not.

There are some reference on internet and in book(s) that this should be supported

[Windows Inside eBook](https://books.google.cz/books?id=QiaFDwAAQBAJ&pg=PT1173&dq=WINDOWS%2010%20INSIDE&hl=cs&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwiDwcqgvrnkAhVjonEKHWLRDzEQ6AEIKTAA#v=snippet&q=RunServicesOnce&f=false)

[Questions from others](https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/forum/all/is-the-registry-key-runservicesonce-still/e0d5f777-e8e8-489e-bfb0-b8d989f7c9e4)

[MSDN](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/179365/info-run-runonce-runservices-runservicesonce-and-startup)

I'm looking for either something I'm doing in wrong way or some tip about where to look for more information. Now it seems that command is not executed at all, no errors in EventLog or anywhere else.

Answer (score 0):

`RunServicesOnce` was once available under:

```
HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\RunServicesOnce  
HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\RunServicesOnce
```

To my knowledge this does not exist any more and dates to Windows NT,
although it is still being listed today along with other Windows NT
and even Windows 3.1 registry entries.

If you want to test if some startup registry entry still exists, use `regedit` to
verify that point.

I suggest to use `RunOnce` instead.